# .net CORS - Losing Allow Origin header when the response is 401 - not authorized

Tags: c#, ajax, cors

I'm trying to determine why/how I'm losing the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the response is 401-Unauthorized.

I'm using token-based authentication where the token has an expiration date.  When this token expires, the server returns a 401-unauthorized, as it should, but in chrome (and IE and FF) it never sees the Allow Origin header and errors with the usual CORS error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://my.rest.service. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.`

I'm not sure any of that is relevant though, as the auth logic works fine, its just that CORS chokes when the response is 401.

### C# CORS handler

```
namespace NViewREST.Handlers
{
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    /// <summary>
    /// Handler for processing Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) requests
    /// </summary>
    public class CorsHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        /// <summary>The origin.</summary>
        private const string Origin = "Origin";
    
        /// <summary>Header indicating we should treat this is CORS request.</summary>
        private const string EnableCors = "X-EnableCors";

        /// <summary>The access control request method.</summary>
        private const string AccessControlRequestMethod = "Access-Control-Request-Method";

        /// <summary>The access control request headers.</summary>
        private const string AccessControlRequestHeaders = "Access-Control-Request-Headers";

        /// <summary>The access control allow origin.</summary>
        private const string AccessControlAllowOrigin = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";

        /// <summary>The access control allow methods.</summary>
        private const string AccessControlAllowMethods = "Access-Control-Allow-Methods";

        /// <summary>The access control allow headers.</summary>
        private const string AccessControlAllowHeaders = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers";

        /// <summary>
        /// send async request
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="request">The request.</param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken">The cancellation token.</param>
        /// <returns>The <see cref="Task"/>.</returns>
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // if it has our NFIB enable CORS header or has the access control request method header, we're assuming CORS request
            var isCorsRequest = request.Headers.Contains(AccessControlRequestMethod) || request.Headers.Contains(EnableCors);

            // preflight == OPTIONS request - usually only sent prior to CORS requests
            var isPreflightRequest = request.Method == HttpMethod.Options;

            // express exit if its a normal request
            if (!isCorsRequest)
            {
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }

            // actual CORS request - add appropriate header before executing as  normal
            if (!isPreflightRequest)
            {
                 return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(
                    t =>
                        {
                            var resp = t.Result;
                            resp.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowOrigin, request.Headers.GetValues(Origin).First());
                            return resp;
                        },
                    cancellationToken);
            }

            // at this point its the preflight request - add headers to indicate allowed origins
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowOrigin, request.Headers.GetValues(Origin).First());

            // add header to indicate allowed methods
            var accessControlRequestMethod = request.Headers.GetValues(AccessControlRequestMethod).FirstOrDefault();
            if (accessControlRequestMethod != null)
            {
                response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowMethods, accessControlRequestMethod);
            }

            // add headers to indicate allowed headers
            var requestedHeaders = string.Join(", ", request.Headers.GetValues(AccessControlRequestHeaders));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestedHeaders))
            {
                response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowHeaders, requestedHeaders);
            }

            // send result of OPTIONS request
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
            tcs.SetResult(response);
            return tcs.Task;
        }
    }
}
```

I can step through the lines that add the header, even when the response is 401, so I know on the .net end is adding it.

### JavaScript Ajax call

```
function executeAjax (method, url, data, token) {

    url = (url.indexOf('/') === 0) ? url : "/" + url;

    var options = {
        method: method,
        url: app.settings.apiUrlRoot + url,
        data: data
    };

    token = token || localStorage.getItem("sessionKey");

    options.headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json",

        //header for enabling CORS
        "X-EnableCors": 'true'
    }

    if (token !== undefined && token !== null)
    {
        options.headers["X-ADAuth"] = token,
    }

    return $.ajax(options);
};
```

The result of this call is the CORS error I referenced earlier.

There are no issues with the firewall or middleware stripping these out that I know of since any other non-401 ajax request executes just fine.

Any thoughts to why the header is disappearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue and solved it by explicitly adding the CORS header to the 401 response before it was returned.

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Add(new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "errorMessage"));
response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowOrigin, "*");
return response;
```

Comment: Which namespace is AccessControlAllowOrigin in?